# How to select distinct items from a list

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have this class

```
class Test
    {
        public string Property { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public List<string> MyProperty { get; set; } 

    }
```

and I create a instance of it

```
 List<Test> t = new List<Test>() {
                new Test() {
                     ID = "1",
                      Property = "2"

                },
                new Test() {
                     ID = "2",
                      Property = "3"
                },
                new Test() {
                     ID = "2",
                     Property = "5"
                }

            };
```

I want to have a List which has distinct elements filteried by ID and also the public List MyProperty { get; set; }  should be filled with  public string Property { get; set; } data.

So the final result should be

```
List<Test> = {
   1.   ID = "1",List<MyProperty> = "2"
   2.   ID = "2",List<MyProperty> = "2"                        

};
```

Comment: `List<MyProperty>` do you mean `List<string> MyPropertyList`  ?  you cannot use the name of a variable as the type.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GroupBy` and `First` to remove duplicates:

```
t.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
t.Distinct(new TestComparer());
```

Where TestComparer is your comparer's implementation.
Here's the [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// Custom comparer for the Test class
class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<Test>
{
    // Tests are equal if their IDs are equal.
    public bool Equals(Test x, Test y)
    {
        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public int GetHashCode(Test test)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(test, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        int hashId = test.Id == null ? 0 : test.Id.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the test.
        return hashId;

        //Should be enough, but you can merge hashcodes of other fields in some way, for example:
        //int hashProperty = test.Property == null ? 0 : test.Property.GetHashCode();
        //return hashId ^ hashProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Insert sample here please... :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `GroupBy()` LINQ extensions:

```
t.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
 .Select(x => new Test {
    ID = x.Key,
    MyProperty = x.Select(y => y.Property).ToList()
 })
 .ToList();
```

Where the param of `GroupBy` is the key you want to group over, so ID in your case.

The `Select` will then project them into the new `Test`

Here are some useful links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx

The result will be:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "MyProperty": [ "2" ],
        "Property": null
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "MyProperty": [ "3", "5" ],
        "Property": null
    },
]
```